# How to receive and read user input through UART (Embedded C)

Tags: c, embedded, uart, receiver

I am trying position control of DC motor with AS5600 encoder with position as input from user through UART but I am unable to do so. If I give a 4 digit input say 1222, only the '1' in ASCII value is stored in Buffer array.

I tried creating an array of array to store each digits of the input through a for loop which are stored as ASCII value in the array and then convert them back to decimal.

```
  for (int j = 0; j < NUM_DIGITS; j++)
  {
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, rxBuffer[i][j], 1, 1000);
    intValue = (intValue * 10) + (rxBuffer[i][j] - '0');
  }
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure without seeing more code, but if the receive routine behaves as I'd expect, you should be passing a pointer to the destination for the read. So, rxBuffer[i][j] would be &(rxBuffer[i[[j]). Again, this is just conjecture. Also, why are you reading one byte at a time?

Comment: Is there even a need to store anything in an arrray, given that you are "consuming" each character as it appears?

Comment: You probably need to specify the MCU and device library - it is not a generic "Embedded C" thing commin to all embedded systems.  Looks like an STM32 using ST's nasty HAL / STM32Cube library?

Comment: Either way , I strongly suggest that you implement a more conventional FIFO bufferes serial I/O (even if it is based on ST's low-level functions) - that HAL stuff s not really intended as an application layer interface - you used it to implement such interfaces.  You might configure your project with stdio based on that UART, then you can use standard library I/O functions.

Comment: what id the data type of `rxBuffer[i][j]`?  Given: `HAL_UART_Receive (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)`, `rxBuffer` woud have to be a two dimensional array of `uint8_t*` which to be frank does not sound very likely, or if it is the case, very sensible.

Answer (score 0):

If `rxBuffer[i][j]` is a 2D array then it means that you do not read the warnings. If it is the case you need to pass address of this element (ie `(uint8_t *)&rxBuffer[i][j]`)

You also do not check the result of the HAL function.

Example of simple line reading function (:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef getString(char *buff, size_t size)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    HAL_StatusTypeDef result;
    while(pos < size - 1 && (result = HAL_UART_Receive(huart, (uint8_t *)(buff + pos), 1)) == HAL_OK)
    {
        if(buff[pos++] == '\n') {pos--;break;}
    }
    buff[pos] = 0;
    return result;
}
```